# SQL Server Agent Job doesn't execute SSIS package Permission Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I am trying to run a SSIS Package (Uploading a file) to my SQL Server Database.
After creating the SSIS Package in SSIS it saves to a folder on SSMS.
I have set it up like the below:

[image]

I basically have all admin rights on this instance.
When I try to run the package I am hit with a fail saying:

> 04/14/2021 10:05:27,Testing SSIS,Error,1,XXXX\INSTANCE04,Testing SSIS,Upload,,Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run ANALYSISCOMMAND job steps without a proxy account.  The step failed

and this error sometimes too:

***04/14/2021 10:05:27,Testing SSIS,Error,1,XXXX\INSTANCE04,Testing SSIS,Upload,,Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run DTS Excecution jobs steps without a proxy account. The step failed***

I plan to run multiple packages in this job later on
If someone could help I would be very grateful!

Comment: Agent tasks don't run under *your* credentials they run under the Agent Service Account; which shouldn't be a `sysadmin`. The error, however, is telling you what to do here... *"Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run ANALYSISCOMMAND job steps without a proxy account"*

Comment: @Larnu Ok thanks for the clarification, so I cannot use Windows Credentials to login? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: *" so I cannot use Windows Credentials to login"* I didn't say that at all; in fact SSIS packages *must* be run under Windows Authentication in SSISDB.

Comment: @Larnu Ok sorry I am unsure what the best approach to the problem is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are processing an analysis services model or cube.  To resolve this, try the following:

1- Add a credential (stores a windows account credentials in SQL Server)

2- Add a proxy and give it permission to process and SSAS Command and run an ssis package

3- Grant permissions to the account used in the credential to process the SSAS model or
cube

4- Configure the job to run under the new proxy account

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE CREDENTIAL [<domain\user>]
WITH
    IDENTITY = N'<domain\user>'
  , SECRET = N'<password>';
GO

USE [msdb];
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_add_proxy
    @proxy_name = N'SSAS_Processor'
  , @credential_name = N'<domain\user>'
  , @enabled = 1;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem
    @proxy_name = N'SSAS_Processor'
  , @subsystem_id = 10; --ssas command
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem
    @proxy_name = N'proxy'
  , @subsystem_id = 11; --ssis package
GO
```

**Configure job:**
[image]

Comment: thsnk you for this. i managed to create a proxy after this post using simialr code to the above. But there seems to be a problem with my Credential Permissions. I am using my correct account and the Credential Creation even autofills my details

Comment: @pandasman, Are you unable to create the credential or is there some other error you can share?